# PHP dom parse code echos each statement thrice instead of once

Tags: php, web-crawler

I have this code to extract statements from a multiple pages of a forum site. it works great except it prints each statement thrice instead of once. I checked each and every line still i don't understand why.

My code goes as:

```
<?php
    set_time_limit(3600);
    $i = 0;

    while($i < 100)
    {
        $e = 839303 - $i;

        require_once('dom/simple_html_dom.php'); 
        $html =file_get_html('http://www.usmleforum.com/files/forum/2017/1/'.$e.'.php');

        foreach ($html->find("tr") as $row)
        {
            $element = $row->find('td.Text2',0);

            if ($element == null) { continue; }

            $textNode = array_filter($element->nodes, function ($n)
            {
                 return $n->nodetype == 3;        //Text node type, like in jQuery     
            });

            if (!empty($textNode))
            {
                $text = current($textNode);
                echo $text."<br>"; 
            }
        }

        $i++;
    }
?>
```

In other hand, if the site that we are extracting contains more than on statements of the hidden somewhere, can we only ask the parser to echo once?

Any help is appreciated..

Trying to parse user details...but not working,, kinda skipping..

```
//User
    $element = $html->find('td.FootNotes2',0);
    if ($element == null) { continue; }
    $textNode = array_filter($element->nodes, function ($n) {
    return $n->nodetype == 3;        
    });
    if (!empty($textNode)) {
    $text = current($textNode);
    echo $text."<br><hr><hr>"; 
    }
```

Comment: Please check if this statement is correct, return $n->nodetype == 3; you intended to put = or ==?

Comment: @manian anything else ?....

Comment: if the site that we are extracting contains more than on statements of the hidden somewhere, can we only ask the parser to echo once? @manian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting 3 outputs of the same text is because of the selection being made and the HTML structure of the page. The entire site is made up of nested tables, and so what is happening is the used query is finding all `<tr>...</tr>` tags on the entire page. Then looping through every `tr` tag and looking for the first `td.Text2` which also shows up in the HTML multiple times on the pages, [example](http://www.usmleforum.com/files/forum/2017/1/839303.php).

This is going to be a tricky crawl given the structure of the HTML and you may be better off searching for only `td.Text2` and grabbing the first one on the page instead. Below is an example of this solution.

Something like seems to work, but the pages are not the same throughout the loop so the results are a little weird:

```
<?php
require_once('dom/simple_html_dom.php');
set_time_limit(3600);
$i = 0;

while ($i < 100) {
    $e = 839303 - $i;
    $html = file_get_html('http://www.usmleforum.com/files/forum/2017/1/'.$e.'.php');
    $i++;

    $element = $html->find('td.Text2',0);

    if ($element == null ) { continue; }

    $textNode = array_filter($element->nodes, function ($n) {
         return $n->nodetype == 3;        //Text node type, like in jQuery
    });

    if (!empty($textNode)) {
        $text = current($textNode);
        echo $text."<br>";
    }

    // Getting User/Author
    $parent = $element->parent()->parent();
    $element = $parent->find('td.FootNotes2',1);
    if ($element == null) { continue; }
    $textNode = array_filter($element->nodes, function ($n) {
      return $n->nodetype == 3;
    });
    if (!empty($textNode)) {
      $text = current($textNode);
      echo $text."<br><hr><hr>";
    }
}
```

Comment: dude, thanks for your time but i tried to add another code to the one you given, to parse user name from the forum site. but it is skipping that statement. please take a look at it. i have uploaded the same in the question details...

Comment: There are mutliple `td.FootNotes2` elements in the HTML, and more importantly the first one seems to always be empty. I edited my answer with a possible solution. When you are crawling/scraping web pages you should look at the raw HTML and identify patterns in the structure.

Comment: yeah... that worked great... thanks man.. i forgot to consider the array indexescompletely